# Problem with normal map

Tags: mesh, uv, normals

This is my low poly

[image]

and this is the high poly

[image]

when i try to bake the high poly onto the low poly with UV smart project 
the results is this

[image]

Why my mesh has these lines? I can't understan why . . .

Comment: What file format are you saving the displacement maps as? I suggest 32 bit float .exr

Comment: Try setting low-poly shading to *Smooth* before baking which is most often desired.

Comment: I'll try to smooth. I save normal maps with png format

Comment: Those lines may also be caused by a `0` difference between the low and high poly mesh (aka where the meshes intersect). Maybe try increasing the size of the high poly slightly, Alt+S (in edit mode)

Comment: i really don't know . . .  i'll try this one too

Comment: Could be that you need more Margin in your bake. Or maybe it's something with a SubSurf mod on the object (if so, try disabling "Subdivide UVs" and re-baking.